# Update labels while checking network connection to hosts using thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm new to this thread world. I saw bunch of tutorials regarding thread but I still find it difficult to use the way i want. What i want is to update a Label right after i got Ping result. The codes below is the working well except it updates all labels at a time after all the ping results are returned. I think using Thread can help me with this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lblPings.Count; i++)
{
    Ping x = new Ping();
    if (txtTo[i].Text.Length > 0)
    {
        PingReply reply = x.Send(IPAddress.Parse(txtTo[i].Text)); 
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            lblPings[i].Text = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() + "ms";
            lblPings[i].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else //if host is not reachable.
        {
            lblPings[i].Text = "Failed";
            lblPings[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into / can you use Async or the BackgroundWorker class?

Comment: BackgroundWorker sounds great. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help here to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

When you set a property on a control, you are *not* telling that control to redraw itself. Instead, two things happen: you change the data the control will use when it redraws itself later anyway, and you send a message to the window system that this control is out of date. You now have to wait for the windowing system to come back and re-*paint* the control before any update happens.

The problem here is that any re-painting happens on  the *same* thread that your event handlers and other normal code uses. This means that you can't possibly update the control using what you think of as normal code until after your entire method has completed and control flow on that thread goes back to the windowing system.

There are a few different ways you can get around this problem, such as DoEvents or Invoke, but I think most of the time the best fit for a Winforms app is to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) control.

Comment: Deeply appreciate your kind explanation. I'll try BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a thread that pings the host indefinitely and stores the result anywhere. The problem is that the thread could not modify anything of the GUI, but there are three possible solutions:

- Using a [delegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109000/C-Delegates-Step-by-Step) function as a callback method of the main gui
- You can store the results in anywhere and check them constantly, from a timer stored in the gui
- Finally you can use [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

Good luck!

Comment: I deeply appreciate your reply. I'll start with your second suggestion.

Comment: Please remember you will have to "protect" the results for mutual exclusion. You can do it using lock: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.80).aspx